# converting array pattern string to array and sort in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, logic

I have a string includig array symbol and double quote

```js
var abc = '["Free WiFi","Breakfast for 2","Accommodation"]'
```

now i want this to convert into array and then sort this array.

the final result i want is Accomodation, Breakfast for 2, Free WiFi.

if array conversion and sorting is not require then also its fine.

how can we do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `JSON.parse` and `.sort`:

```js
var abc = JSON.parse('["Free WiFi","Breakfast for 2","Accommodation"]').sort().join(', ')
console.log(abc);
```

Comment: it works but show like Accomodation,Breakfast for 2,Free Wifi. how can i add blank space every after comma? i want Accomodation, Breakfast for 2, Free Wifi.

Comment: probably just do `.join(', ')` at the end

Answer (score 0):

Another option just for fun

```js
var abc = '["Free WiFi","Breakfast for 2","Accommodation"]';

// With help of RegExp
match = (abc.replace(/(?:\[)*\"(.*?)\"(?:\])*/g, (m,g) => g)).split(",").sort().join(', ');

// Log
console.log(match)
```